# I can't generate an IPA file from Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying build my iOS application from Visual Studio for generate an IPA file, but I'm not having success.I set it up my provisioning profile, with my AppID etc, and when I try compile iOS application, gives following error:

> "D:\AppNivel_Bkp_14032018_1450h\AppNivel\AppNivel.iOS\AppNivel.iOS.csproj"
>   (default target) (1) -> (_CodesignAppBundle target) ->  C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(1930,3):
>   error :
>   /Users/user122749/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/Users/carlo/Desktop/IOS/AppNivel.iOS.app:
>   unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff"

[image]

Comment: Have you provided a bundle name?

Comment: Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=vsmac

Comment: Yes, I've already tried with bundle name, and I followed it all step by step.

I think the problem is with the certificate, because the error occurs with the tag <Codesign>